# java - separate business logic from enum based singleton class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums

I have implemented a **java singleton class** using **enum** approach. The code of that class is given below.

My question is: How can I **separate the business logic** from this singleton class or separate the other functions which are other than the creation of singleton class?

Since right now I have declared the whole class as an enum, should I declare it as a class, and then make an enum attribute inside it or take another approach?

Here is my code of singleton.

```
enum TransactionHelper implements ISerialize
{
  Instance;

  private int serializePreFixCount = 1;

  /**
   * This method serializes transaction on Disk.
   */
  @Override
  public void serializeOnDisk()
  {
    //some code here

  }

  /**
   * This method serializes transaction on network stream.
   */
  @Override
  public void serializeOnNetwork()
  {
    //some code here
  }

}
```

And when I need to use this class I use it like this.

```
TransactionHelper.Instance.serializeOnNetwork();
TransactionHelper.Instance.serializeOnDisk();
```

Thanks.

Comment: "How can I separate the business logic from this singleton?" - assuming it handles the singleton - you don't!

Comment: why a singleton?  Specifically, if foo and bar each have distinct instances of `TransactionHelper`, what would happen?  Please explain, or give stack trace, showing error.

Comment: singelton should only allows you to create one object. No matter if foo and bar instantiate their own, they still have the same object.

Answer (score 1):

To separate business logic, you should use [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

```
enum TransactionHelper implements ISerialize {

    Instance(new SerializeImpl());

    private int serializePreFixCount = 1;
    private final ISerialize delegate;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    TransactionHelper(ISerialize delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    /**
     * This method serializes transaction on Disk.
     */
    @Override
    public void serializeOnDisk() {
        delegate.serializeOnDisk();
    }

    /**
     * This method serializes transaction on network stream.
     */
    @Override
    public void serializeOnNetwork() {
        delegate.serializeOnNetwork();
    }

}
```

**Now you can put all serialization logic in `SerializeImpl` class.**

---

Also, you could use use a class in stead of enum if you did not mind changing the usage from

```
TransactionHelper.Instance.serializeOnNetwork();
TransactionHelper.Instance.serializeOnDisk();
```

to

```
TransactionHelper.getInstance().serializeOnNetwork();
TransactionHelper.getInstance().serializeOnDisk();
```

So, just make the constructor private and you can get your singleton

```
class TransactionHelper {

    private TransactionHelper() { }

    private static TransactionHelper getInstance() {
        TransactionHelperHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class TransactionHelperHolder {
        private static final TransactionHelper INSTANCE = new TransactionHelper();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check it out in practical and i will get back to you

Comment: I have implmented it but there is a design problem that if i put all my serialization logic into **SerializeImpl** class, then i have to make its constructor public. Then it means that any other class could instantiate that class. But in my case i don't want any class to call serialization methods.

Comment: You could make it package private. Classes in your own package can always follow the discipline. Otherwise, you should not delegate at all and have everything in the same class.